# heroku Push rejected cant find the error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm working with rails and just finished. local works everything perfect, but push up to Heroku is not working. I searched everywhere but I don't understand really the Heroku logfile.
I fixed some errors but it's still not working. after the Yarn download is this rake aborted!

```
remote:        Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
remote:        Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
remote:        I, [2017-12-13T20:24:49.127264 #1613]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/public/assets/background-55c706ba724665dd45dd39541947c50a9859524d07ed7fc00b66fd78a99676ea.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-12-13T20:24:49.129988 #1613]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/public/assets/background2-ef109488fe2e07d4b632e0585eaf5d790f6c76cd0ca6bab49205ea2d109b9faf.jpg
remote:        I, [2017-12-13T20:24:49.132840 #1613]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/public/assets/logo-b5e4a8b5b47d679c0486c4d9c32da4acbf49f32cb86d9437ee05b927940a9a11.png
remote:        I, [2017-12-13T20:24:49.136007 #1613]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/public/assets/logo1-58014e47d65fe69689f38789fd525c155afd84ada92f80fa06ad2471f26a0eb5.png
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token punc «,», expected punc «:»
remote:        JS_Parse_Error.get ((execjs):3538:621)
remote:        (execjs):4060:47
remote:        (execjs):1:102
remote:        Object.<anonymous> ((execjs):1:120)
remote:        Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
remote:        Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
remote:        Module.load (module.js:487:32)
remote:        tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
remote:        Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
remote:        Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in `exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:21:in `eval'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:46:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/uglifier-9abd18da4f5e/lib/uglifier.rb:195:in `run_uglifyjs'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/uglifier-9abd18da4f5e/lib/uglifier.rb:157:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:53:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_c0948d29239961f8305c09dc5523c4b6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to bungee-choreograpy.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/bungee-choreograpy.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/bungee-choreograpy.git'
```

Comment: It's a shame that you don't understand the Heroku logfile. Perhaps if you were to share it with us, we might be able to help.

Comment: Try running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` in your dev environment. You will probably get an error, but it may give you a clue how to fix this.

Comment: There's likely a syntax error. `ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token punc «,», expected punc «:»` - you have a comma somewhere that only a colon would make sense.

Comment: thank you, Tom . just did it I get no error.
info No lock file found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
info Lockfile not saved, no dependencies.

Comment: Hi Kodi, I checked my js file and I think its everything ok. the app works perfect local. without any error

Comment: Tom, I did the rake assets: precompile, then committed and then it works. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tom, I just did rake assets: precompile again. then commit and push up to Heroku and it works!